# Why goland's terminal is not using configuration in .zshrc

Tags: shell, ide, zsh, goland

I'm using goland's terminal to run commands. I noticed that it doesn't apply my configuration in `~/.zshrc`. For example, I have couple lines to configure shortcuts in my `~/.zshrc`

```
bindkey "^[backward-word" backward-word
bindkey "^[forward-word" forward-word
bindkey "^[line-begin" beginning-of-line
bindkey "^[line-end" end-of-line
bindkey "^[undo" undo
bindkey "^[del-prev-word" backward-delete-word
bindkey "^[u" backward-kill-line
```

And when I open iterm, this configs are applied. But when I'm using the terminal in goland, it doesn't follow these rules. I'm wondering how can I config the shortcuts in goland's terminal too.

Comment: (1) Why are you tagging the question as _bash_ **and** _zsh_, when you configure only for zsh? (2) Did you ensure that you are really running zsh inside _goland_? (3) What is the setting of your `TERM` variable?

Comment: I'd say that it depends on how you start GoLand. Try to run it via zsh, so the IDE can pick up your environment variables. Otherwise, the configuration isn't passed to the GUI apps.

Comment: Got the same bug at the latest GoLand and Ubuntu.

I had test other ide of jetbrains, only GoLand reproduced the problem.

The bug is strange,  i thought the terminal not load .zshrc, but zsh theme is normal as .zshrc defined, the environment is failed.